# JavaFX root Menu & Split Screen in 1 display

Tags: javafx, menu, split, root, scene

I am trying to have a root menu up top & then do a split screen below.

I found a website online here "http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/".
It that has the example that I am trying to do.
I want to hard code with real codes, not use some drag and drop stuff like he does.

So far I am able to write the program & display the Menu via root & run everything but I can not figure out how to add a "Split screen" below it without causing issues.

Every time I try to add split screen implementations along with the menu in root, it will not work.

I can do it in `JFrame`, but I want it done in JavaFX root.

I can not find anything online about it, seriously been stumped for 4 hours on this.

[image: This image is what I am trying to do.]

(Project title is "WorkAir")
Here is my current code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class WorkAir extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.setTitle("WorkAir");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 550, Color.WHITE);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
        root.setTop(menuBar);

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                System.out.println("Platform & System Exit");
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // File Menu

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem newMenuItem = new MenuItem("New");
        MenuItem saveMenuItem = new MenuItem("Save");
        MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.getItems().addAll(newMenuItem, saveMenuItem,
            new SeparatorMenuItem(), exitMenuItem);

        //File Menu Trees

        exitMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                //File Menu Trees Exit
                Label secondLabel = new Label("Are you sure you want to exit?");
                Button buttonNo = new Button();

                buttonNo.setStyle("-fx-font: 10 arial; -fx-base: #d3d3d3;");
                buttonNo.setTranslateX(-55);
                buttonNo.setTranslateY(30);

                Button buttonYes = new Button();

                buttonYes.setStyle("-fx-font: 10 arial; -fx-base: #d3d3d3;");
                buttonYes.setTranslateX(+55);
                buttonYes.setTranslateY(30);

                buttonNo.setText("Exit, No");
                buttonNo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                        System.out.println("No");
                        Stage secondStage = (Stage) buttonNo.getScene().getWindow();
                        secondStage.close();
                    }

                });

                buttonYes.setText("Exit, Yes");
                buttonYes.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                        System.out.println("Yes");
                        Platform.exit();
                    }

                });

                StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
                secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);
                secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(buttonNo);
                secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(buttonYes);

                Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 350, 150);

                Stage secondStage = new Stage();
                secondStage.setTitle("Exit");
                secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

                //Set position of second window, related to primary window.
                secondStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 250);
                secondStage.setY(primaryStage.getY() + 100);
                secondStage.centerOnScreen();

                secondStage.show();
            }
        });

        //2nd Menu
        Menu secondMenu = new Menu("2nd");
        CheckMenuItem htmlMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("HTML");
        htmlMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        secondMenu.getItems().add(htmlMenuItem);

        CheckMenuItem cssMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("CSS");
        cssMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        secondMenu.getItems().add(cssMenuItem);

        //3rd Menu
        Menu thirdMenu = new Menu("3rd");
        ToggleGroup tGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioMenuItem mysqlItem = new RadioMenuItem("MySQL");
        mysqlItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);

        RadioMenuItem oracleItem = new RadioMenuItem("Oracle");
        oracleItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);
        oracleItem.setSelected(true);

        thirdMenu.getItems().addAll(mysqlItem, oracleItem,
            new SeparatorMenuItem());

        Menu Menu = new Menu("Sub Menu");
        Menu.getItems().addAll(
            new CheckMenuItem("1"),
            new CheckMenuItem("2"),
            new CheckMenuItem("3"));

        secondMenu.getItems().add(Menu);

        //Menu Bar Get All
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, secondMenu, thirdMenu);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the guy on the website of the concept I want... he uses 
"Load root layout from fxml file". So he is using drag & drop methods using fxml, which is the easy way in my opinion. I want to learn how to truly code it tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`SplitPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) for this purpose.

Here's a short simple example. Of course in real code you'd keep references to `Node`s you need to access in some variables:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(new TableView(),
                                        new VBox(new Label("some other content")));

    splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    // place splitPane as center
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(splitPane);

    borderPane.setTop(new MenuBar(new Menu("File")));

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```